# When a wcf client talks to wcf service, what happens internally

Tags: wcf, networking, network-protocols, channelfactory

When a wcf client talks to wcf service, what happens internally?

I mean looking at bit low level, which all component of wcf/.net/"soap standards" takes part in this communication?

How client's request reaches to wcf service, then who listens and responds to request arrived for  a wcf service (I know it's service host on highest level, want to know what part of host does that i.e. which process/unit).

In short looking for directions to know in detail what makes wcf client to service communication happen, which all events/processes take place during it high level?